# How to create custom drupal 8 module

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I am sure this question will irritate many old Drupal developers, but I just need a quick fix.
I want to

1. create a brand new custom module by a hook to an existing contributed module.
2. introduce a feature in my new module which is an alteration of a feature (e.g form) in the parent module.

Can someone please walk me through the coding ?

Say for example , I want to create my custom module from the simpleads module (https://www.drupal.org/project/simpleads), and my module needs to alter some forms in the src/forms folder.
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have the same problem. Most module creation tutorials just show how to output content on a page. I just need a custom module to alter a contrib module and now the question is how to structure it and where to put the code.